# click on a link event webbrowser c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I want to open a link in IE browser from the web browser control in my winform ... the webbrowser control navigate to a page when the user click on a link it opens in the internet explorer browser.

Answer (score 7):

Basically handle the [WebBrowser.Navigating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx), cancel the navigation and open up the url in explorer like this:

```
private void WebBrowserNavigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = true;
  Process.Start("iexplorer.exe", e.Url);
}
```

Comment: how would this code look in vb.net, I'm having a bit of trouble making it work