# open IE when click on a link in the webbrowser c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, webbrowser-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [click on a link event webbrowser c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309595/click-on-a-link-event-webbrowser-c)

```
webbrowser1.navigate("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

this is the initiale page that will load in the webbrowser1 control on the Form_load event. I want to open the IE when the user click on any link in that webpage ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting the same thing as in this question/answer?

[click on a link event webbrowser c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309595/click-on-a-link-event-webbrowser-c)