# Creating Instance of window from from browser contol

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to create an instance of window form when using browser control. i.e when i click on link it will create instance of window form.

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309595/click-on-a-link-event-webbrowser-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
WebBrowser browser;
...
browser.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptingObject();
...
browser.DocumentText="<a onclick=\"window.external.WantCookie('Cookie')\">Give some cookie</a>";
....


[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public class ScriptingObject
{
    public void WantCookie(String message)
    {
        if(message=="Cookie")
            MessageBox.Show("Thanks");
        else MessageBox.Show("I want Cookie!");
    }
}
```